# If Linux is installed in a virtual environment on my mac can I open apps that big sur blocks?

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying open this application: [http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~lucag/](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/%7Elucag/) (It's a research tool might might be great for my work so I really want to access it).

When I try and open the app I get the message: "You do not have permission to open the application "ECGWorkbench'. Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance."

If I installed Linux in a virtual environment on my mac could I then open the the Linux version of the app?

Comment: the general answer is yes, however, when writing out the question I realized: If you can't open an application, you most likely won't be able to install a whole virtual machine, due to the lack of admin rights. Or are you admin and something else is stopping you from opening the app?

Comment: Do you have access to something like fakeroot

Comment: Surely the general answer is no. Linux has nothing to do with macos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be yes from an OS view, as the Linux VM would be a self contained system. However, beware of ports blocked by your proxy or any firewall filtering however, as the application could be denied access to external resources by the network your host machine is on.

Comment: Thank you. I gave it a go and it didn't work (for either Linux and Windows) but at least I know the problem is with the app rather than how I was running the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have Linux installed in a virtualised environment that you control on your Mac - then you could install applications in there. Restrictions on running applications within macOS using Apple's MDM system would not apply to applications within the virtualised Linux system.

Note that this all presumes that you have already got Linux up and running in a virtualised environment. If the owner of your laptop denies running most programs, they most probably also deny the installation of virtualisation software.